# Dynamically load Combo box in Windows Installer UI created using InstallShiled

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

I am creating windows installer using InstallShield 2012. My installer UI having combo box and data for combo box is given in Combo box "Items" property. Instead of adding it statically, I need to load the combo box values at run time from a text file. It seems we can use the script to read the file and set to combo box. But my question is, how to ship and get the path of that text file?.

For example, in Wix, we can pack the text file using  element in Wix bundle project. So, the corresponding file is extracted from the setup while launching and placed in temp folder. We can get that file from that location and dynamically load UI data.

Like this, What option is available in InstallShield to embed file with setup.exe and access it in installation time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add the file to the Binary table. This will then be extracted to the directory defined by the [SOURCEDIR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371857(v=vs.85).aspx). You'll probably want to have a custom action update this text file with your dynamic changes.

Comment: Actually, I want to load the combo box items dynamically (read contents from text file and load) on setup installation UI. But the text file which contains list items will not be shipped to INSTALLDIR. Is your solution work for this scenario? Can you please provide the sample steps/script?

Comment: Yes. When your install is run it will extract the files in the Binary table to the location where the extracted MSI is running from. This is defined by the SOURCEDIR at run time.

Create a custom action to parse this extracted file in the SOURCEDIR location and add to your combo box property